# CMS For College

Tags: content-management-system

Let's say you need to rewrite a university website, the key feature being the ability to give certain users permission to edit certain parts of the site, and the editing would all have to happen in-browser.

I've been searching around, looking at various CMSs that fit the build here, but I'm wondering what your opinions are.

So, if you were to have to rewrite the system i described above, what CMS would you use? If none fit the build, would you suggest rolling your own instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate reaction was: [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/). It's currently at 3.1.2 and is a far cry from the simple blogging software it started as. Starting with V3 it took a strong step toward being a CMS. Its multisite feature supports multiple-sub-websites (e.g. for different departments), and it has reasonable support for role-based ACL. It has built-in WYSIWYG editing, and something over 12,000 extensions to had various types of functionality.

Something to remember is that many college sites are being supported by "whoever hasn't graduated yet." This makes long-term maintainability of the core code an important consideration. This is another check in the Win column for WP.

One word of warning: only consider themes that are *strongly* oriented toward V3+. Also note that themes are more than just a paint job -- they can add major chunks of task-specific functionality. Once you commit to using a theme you may find it challenging to switch to another without a certain amount of local customization.

WordPress is not perfect, but it may be everything you need. Check it out. It's free, extensible, and you clan play with it over a weekend and get a feel for how well it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your stated requirement is surely available in almost any CMS you care to mention.